# In Django admin, how can I filter a MultipleChoiceField depending on a previous MultipleChoiceField?

Tags: django, django-admin

In my django website, I have 3 classes: Thing, Category and SubCategory.
Thing  has 2 ForeignKeys: "Category" and "SubCategory" (such as Car and Ferrari).
SubCategory has 1 ForeighKey: "Category" (Ferrari is in the category Car)

When I create an instance of Thing in the Admin part and when I choose a Category, I would like that the "SubCategory" field only shows the SubCategories linked to the Category I chose. Is that possible?

I saw the possibility to change the AdminForm like:

```
class ThingFormAdmin(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self,Category,*args,**kwargs):
        super (ThingFormAdmin,self ).__init__(*args,**kwargs) # populates the post
        self.fields['sub_category'].queryset = SubCategory.objects.filter(category= ... )
```

But I don't know what to write on the ...

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

in general always this solution would work:
you need some javascript to catch what has been selected for first selection. then do filtering agin using javascript.

but in django admin, there is `autocomplete_fields` available. using this would create a kind of selection-input that uses ajax to do some magic filtering on choices when user types some characters. it uses the `get_search_results` method of the related models admin.ModelAdmin class. overriding that method and giving some extra data to that method could help. but it's the longest way to walk.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! I will look in the 1st answer after the 2nd, because the fact that I don't have to write JS is very nice, as I am very bad in it.

I manage to use the `autocomplete_field` to work, but I am stuck with the redefinition of the `get_search_results` method. If I understood correctly the doc, it will be something like:

```
def get_search_results(self, request, queryset, search_term):
        queryset, use_distinct = super().get_search_results(request, queryset, search_term)
        try:
            cat = search_term
        except ValueError:
            queryset |= self.model.objects.all()
        else:
            queryset |= self.model.objects.filter(category=cat)
        return queryset, use_distinct
```

But I don't understand from where this `search_term` comes from, and how I can specify it. Any ideas?